# Make logo redirect to main page? (How to add hyperlink to image?)

Tags: html, image

Currently, the HTML code for my logo thus far is...

```
<div align="center">
<img width='300' height='40' src='/img/logo.png' />
</div>
```

How would I make it so that if I clicked this image, it would redirect me to the main page?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest an HTML tutorial/book. In any case, let's get this accepted and over with...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div align="center">
<a href="/"><img width='300' height='40' src='/img/logo.png' /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I was forgetting to end it in `</a>`

Answer (score 2):

wrap the `img` in an anchor element (`a`) and grant it with the `href` containing the homepage link.